# How to bypass empty dataset during merge in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am working on creating and merging different datasets. Below is the code attached that I am using. I couldn't share the data because it is confidential.

```
df_unique = pd.merge(df7,df6_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_twos = pd.merge(df9,df8_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_twos_unique = df_twos[df_twos.index % 2 == 0]
df_threes = pd.merge(df11,df10_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_threes_unique = df_threes[df_threes.index % 3 == 0]
df_fours = pd.merge(df13,df12_1,on='DEL_KEY1',how='left')
df_fours_unique = df_fours[df_fours.index % 4 == 0]
df_append1 = df_unique.append(df_twos_unique)
df_append2 = df_append1.append(df_threes_unique)
df_append3 = df_append2.append(df_fours_unique)
```

"df_fours" is erroring out because this is an empty dataset. How do I bypass this line of code? Is a for loop needed? If so, how would I create it? Ultimately, I want this part of the script to execute through the append statements and export the results as csv.

Comment: You can use `if df.empty: ...`

Comment: you either need to put an exception block in for put an if statement before to ignore any dataframes with no rows. Your code looks overly complex - you can't add a sample of the inputs with your desired output? see [mcve] and [ask]